# How to debug into CvCapture_FFMPEG from opencv codes ,avoid cap_ffmpeg.cpp load "opencv_ffmpeg.dll"

Tags: debugging, opencv, ffmpeg

I had got ffmpeg source and build their libs and dlls within my include,lib,bin folders,and I import it into my Opencv project/opencv_highgui, and give the project right property settings.
At the same time, I delete opencv_ffmpeg.dll in Opencv Origin folder.
But it still cant step into ffmpeg source. In debug mode,it just stoped  when it go into class CvCaptrue_FFMPEG_proxy's virtual open()function.
So my question is :
1.how to step into ffmpeg codes? 
2.how to build the opencv_ffmpeg.dll for debug?

Comment: what are you using to debug?

Comment: I using vc++ for debug and tracing opencv function cvCaptureFromFile().

Comment: Now it is ok.just for modify cap_ffmpeg.cpp for not loading always from "opencv_ffmpeg.dll"